# os.close to close open word document

Tags: python

I am trying to check if a file exists, if it does exist, I want to check if it is open by trying to rename it.  The except block is trying to close the open file using os.close.  When I try to close the file I get "TypeError: an integer is required".

```
import os
filepath = "C:\Users\oneilp6\Desktop"
file1 = filepath + "\\HelpFile.docx"
file2 = filepath + "\\HelpFile2.docx"
if os.path.exists(file1):
    try:
        os.rename(file1,file2)
    except:
        os.close(file1)
```

Anyone have any thoughts or ideas?  I am trying to close a word document that is actually open in MS Word.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: `ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA(None, 'this file is open and locked. please close it', 'cannot rename file', 0)`?

Comment: Well 1) You've never opened the file so you don't need to close it, 2) As per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.close) `os.close` takes a file handle you should have access to and 3) isn't renaming a file to see if it's open a terrible idea?

Comment: Do you mean "open" in the sense of "The Python process has an open filehandle pointing to that file" or in the sense of "The user currently has some application running with the file open in it"?  `os.close` is meant for the former, not the latter.

Comment: As an aside, this is a windows-only thing. Unix-like systems will gladly rename open files.

Comment: This is in a Windows OS setting and I mean open in the sense that the file is actually open on the screen, by MS Word. So I guess this method would not work...

Answer (score 2):

You are checking whether the file is open by a different application on your computer. If it is, there isn't much this program can do about it. You don't get to close other program's files. You could potentially hunt down that program and kill it, but even that isn't easy. There are some suggestions at https://serverfault.com/questions/1966/how-do-you-find-what-process-is-holding-a-file-open-in-windows.

Answer (score 0):

There is no file opened in the `except`. so no need to call os.close().
https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.rename

> **os.close()** This function is intended for low-level I/O and must be
>   applied to a file descriptor as returned by os.open() or pipe(). To
>   close a “file object” returned by the built-in function open() or by
>   popen() or fdopen(), use its close() method.